# MySQL server crashing on launch on Ubuntu server

Tags: permissions, mysql

So, whenever I try to launch/install MySQL server it crashes with this log

```
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
2019-01-15T05:42:42.237951Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-01-15T05:42:42.239858Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) starting as process 25348 ...
2019-01-15T05:42:42.242935Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to /var/lib/mysql/
2019-01-15T05:42:42.242951Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-01-15T05:42:42.242968Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2019-01-15T05:42:42.243042Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Now, this folder its talking about, /var/lib/mysql now wait. alot of my apps are crashing on startup talking about var being "world writeable". and I remember accidentally running chmod -R 777 on /var. so, I think it's a problem with the entirety of /var. if anyone can somehow figure out the original permissions with this and can help me fix this, I will be VERY grateful when I run ls -la /var I get

```
ep1c_m1n10n@vault1:/$ ls -la /var
total 64
drwxrwxrwx 16 root root   4096 Aug 18 23:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root   4096 Jan 15 05:15 ..
drwx------  2 root root   4096 Jan 14 06:25 backups
drwx------ 17 root root   4096 Jan 15 02:53 cache
drwx------  2 root root   4096 Jan 15 04:56 crash
drwx------ 51 root root   4096 Jan 15 05:11 lib
drwx--S---  2 root staff  4096 Apr 24  2018 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Apr 26  2018 lock -> /run/lock
drwx------ 19 root syslog 4096 Jan 15 04:56 log
drwx--S---  2 root mail   4096 Apr 26  2018 mail
drwx------  3 root root   4096 Nov 29 01:42 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Apr 26  2018 run -> /run
drwx------  3 root root   4096 Jul 16  2018 snap
drwx------  8 root root   4096 Jan 13 12:17 spool
drwx------ 10 root root   4096 Jan 15 05:39 tmp
drwx------  3 root bin    4096 Jul 16 19:42 usermin
drwx------  5 root bin    4096 Jan 15 04:49 webmin
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root   4096 Jul 16  2018 www
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with /var needs to be

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Mar 23  2016 var
```

The contents of /var that we both have I have this:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4096 Apr 11  2014 local
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 16  2014 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Jun 13  2014 lock -> /run/lock
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Jun 13  2014 run -> /run
drwxrwsrwt  2 root mail   4096 Apr 10  2016 mail
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   4096 Aug  2  2016 spool
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 Aug  2  2016 cache
drwxr-xr-x 57 root root   4096 Jul 25  2017 lib
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Jul 27 06:25 crash
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jul 28 06:25 backups
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Nov  7 14:55 tmp
drwxrwxr-x 12 root syslog 4096 Nov 19 06:25 log
```

- My www is a sym,link so not including that one.

> chmod -R 777 on /var

You did more than that. Lots of files amd directories you show do not have 777 set.

Comment: hmm, i might have changed some things with permissions while copy/pasting stuff from the internet trying to fix this. but the problems started after i set /var to 777. samba and proftpd broke at the same time

Comment: setting /var to drwxr-xr-x or 755 made it work

Comment: Pfew ;) glad you got it working again